# Example in documentation of `tabularray` does not work

Tags: pdftex, tabularray

I am trying to use `tabularray` for multi-page tables that span the whole `\textwidth`. However, I fail even at running the examples from the documentation ([tabularray.pdf](https://mirror.dogado.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf) page 38).

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
        \SetTblrStyle{firsthead}{font=\bfseries}
        \SetTblrStyle{firstfoot}{fg=blue2}
        \SetTblrStyle{middlefoot}{\itshape}
        \SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{red2}
    }
    \begin{longtblr}[
        theme = fancy,
        caption = {A Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Table},
        entry = {Short Caption},
        label = {tblr:test},
        note{a} = {It is the first footnote.},
        note{$\dag$} = {It is the second long long long long long long footnote.},
        remark{Note} = {Some general note. Some general note. Some general note.},
        remark{Source} = {Made up by myself. Made up by myself. Made up by myself.},
        ]{
            colspec = {XXX}, width = 0.85\linewidth,
            rowhead = 2, rowfoot = 1,
            row{odd} = {gray9}, row{even} = {brown9},
            row{1-2} = {purple7}, row{Z} = {blue7},
        }
        \hline
        Head & Head & Head \\
        \hline
        Head & Head & Head \\
        \hline
        Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
        \hline
        Epsilon & Zeta\TblrNote{a} & Eta \\
        \hline
        Iota & Kappa\TblrNote{$\dag$} & Lambda \\
        \hline
        Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
        \hline
        Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
        \hline
        Phi & Chi & Psi \\
        \hline
        ......
        \hline
        Alpha & Beta & Gamma \\
        \hline
        Epsilon & Zeta & Eta \\
        \hline
        Iota & Kappa & Lambda \\
        \hline
        Nu & Xi & Omicron \\
        \hline
        Rho & Sigma & Tau \\
        \hline
        Phi & Chi & Psi \\
        \hline
        Foot & Foot & Foot \\
        \hline
    \end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test shows several problems.

1. Probably not the actual problem, but worth mentioning: `\hline` shouldn't be used here, and the "new syntax" described in the manual should be favored instead.
2. Package `xcolor` should be loaded, otherwise color-related parameters don't work.
3. The line:

```
        ......
```

between two `\hline` is missing `\\` at the end of the line.

The biggest problem is probably 3), since it's a pure syntax error. I assume that the author didn't mean this line to be typed literally, but wanted to say "type as many lines as you wish here so that the tabular doesn't fit on a single page".

Problem 2) is minor, `xcolor` usually gets loaded anyway, manually or automatically by other packages.

Comment: Thanks. I had taken the example directly from the documentation. Why would they use `\hline` if they also discourage it? The `......` I should have seen and removed. Still examples should work out of the box...

Comment: @mrCarnivore The manual shows both the new syntax (which is cleaner, but a bit unusual for old LaTeX users) and the old one. It's probably too early to discard the old one, or it might not be a good idea if they want users with established habits to adopt their package. So examples in the manual show both, depending on the paragraph.